# Retrieving ID from URL

Tags: django

Django question here. So in my base.html, I have a header. The header has links that go to user specific pages. That is, URL's like: /1234/home, /1234/about, etc. where 1234 is the id of a user. My question is, if I want to create a url pointing to a django view method called `home` with signature `home (request, user=0)` where `user` is a different user from the logged in user, how would I do this in the template? To clarify, I am using Django's `{% url ... %}` template tag and I can't just do `{% url [view_name] request.user.id %}` because I want the user id from the url, not the id of the logged in user. Additionally, I would prefer avoiding passing a template variable to get the id of the user in the url because then I would have to do that on every page.

Answer (score 0):

[Get the `id`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request) you want as a `kwarg` to your view, and pass it as a variable to your template through the context to use in the `{url ...}`.

Comment: I don't really want to use a template variable as mentioned in the post, though. This is because every page in the site extends base so if I were to pass this as a template var, my code wouldn't be very DRY as i'll have to pass the id from every view

Comment: @BobbyS. I have no idea what you mean by page, you can use one class based view to get the id and pass it to the context, and then you can extend that base class for each view you want to make.

Comment: That's a bit more refactoring then I would like to do. I decided to just create a custom template tag called {% id_url [view_name] %} and in that tag i'll just parse out the id in request.path and use that for the reverse function

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist a variable across all your templates, look at context processors.  They are added to each `RequestContext` so they are accessible to all templates assuming you use the `render` shortcut or pass the `RequestContext` to your `template.render`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext

https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/core/context_processors.py

There are some default ones that django uses.  It's fairly simple to add your own.
I imagine your context processor will look something like

context_processors.py

```
def id_from_url(request):
   # Find url id component in request.path
   return { 'url_id' : url_id }
```

Then just add to your settings file `appname.context_processors.id_from_url`